# Multiple properties assignment

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda, dry

I was looking for a way to implement DRY principle in my code. I had a code like that.

```
private static bool Inconsistent(AdStats adStat)
{
  return
    adStat.Daily.Impressions != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.Impressions) ||
    adStat.Daily.Clicks != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.Clicks) ||
    adStat.Daily.Spent != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.Spent) ||
    adStat.Daily.SocialImpressions != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.SocialImpressions) ||
    adStat.Daily.SocialClicks != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.SocialClicks) ||
    adStat.Daily.SocialSpent != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.SocialSpent) ||
    adStat.Daily.UniqueImpressions != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.UniqueImpressions) ||
    adStat.Daily.UniqueClicks != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.UniqueClicks) ||
    adStat.Daily.SocialUniqueImpressions != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.SocialUniqueImpressions) ||
    adStat.Daily.SocialUniqueClicks != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => h.Value.SocialUniqueClicks);
}
```

Then with the help of the community i have been given a wonderful solution.

```
 Func<AdStatsItem, int>[] metricGetters = {
     s => s.Impressions,
     s => s.Clicks,
     s => s.Spent,
     //...
 };

  return metricGetters.Any(getter => getter(adStat.Daily)
                                  != adStat.Hourly.Sum(h => getter(h.Value)));
```

But i could not think of a way to use the same technique for a code with multiple assignments.

```
  hourly.Impressions += delta.Impressions;
  hourly.Clicks += delta.Clicks;
  hourly.Spent += delta.Spent;
  hourly.SocialImpressions += delta.SocialImpressions;
  hourly.SocialClicks += delta.SocialClicks;
  hourly.SocialSpent += delta.SocialSpent;
  hourly.UniqueImpressions += delta.UniqueImpressions;
  hourly.SocialUniqueImpressions += delta.SocialUniqueImpressions;
  hourly.UniqueClicks += delta.UniqueClicks;
  hourly.SocialUniqueClicks += delta.SocialUniqueClicks;
```

And after some thinking i came up with this.

```
  Expression<Func<AdStatsItem, int>>[] metricGetters = {
     stat => stat.Impressions,
     stat => stat.Clicks,
     //...
  };

  var type = typeof (AdStatsItem);

  foreach (var metric in metricGetters)
  {

    var body = (MemberExpression)metric.Body;
    var propertyName = body.Member.Name;
    var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

    var val = (int)prop.GetValue(hourly, null) + (int)prop.GetValue(delta, null);

    prop.SetValue(hourly, val, null);        
  }
```

But the usage of reflection really bugs me. Is there a better way get rid of aforementioned redundancy?

Comment: In this case you won't gain anything by factoring. You could enhance it if you have some hypotheses about the properties you use like all the public numerical properties. Otherwise you will end up with a bunch of code far less readable than you current implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your existing code is perfectly fine.** There are limits to what is easily generalizable in C# and unfortunately, you've hit a case that isn't.  The solutions you have available have a certain amount of "fixed cost" (mostly readability) associated with them; I feel they would only help if you had *hundreds* of such properties and/or aggregator-routines.

That said, if you really wanted a general "incrementer" over a list of properties, I would much rather use expression-trees than pure reflection. It's much cleaner, it's "inspectable", it's modifiable,  and you only pay the assembly cost once (subsequent costs to a compiled delegate with straightforward IL are cheap).

```
static Action<AdStatsItem, AdStatsItem> GetAggregateUpdater
       (IEnumerable<Expression<Func<AdStatsItem, int>>> metricGetters)
{
    var aggregate = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AdStatsItem), "aggregate");
    var delta = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AdStatsItem), "delta");

    var increments = from metricGetter in metricGetters
                     let memberExpression = (MemberExpression)metricGetter.Body
                     let property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member
                     select Expression.AddAssign
                             (Expression.Property(aggregate, property),
                              Expression.Property(delta, property));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<AdStatsItem, AdStatsItem>>
                 (Expression.Block(increments), aggregate, delta);

    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

The generated lambda (with your example metrics) looks like this:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Action`2[AdStatsItem,AdStatsItem]>(
    AdStatsItem $aggregate,
    AdStatsItem $delta) {
    .Block() {
        $aggregate.Impressions += $delta.Impressions;
        $aggregate.Clicks += $delta.Clicks;
        $aggregate.Spent += $delta.Spent
    }
}
```

...which is pretty much the *same* as the "hard-coded" solution.

Usable like this:

```
Expression<Func<AdStatsItem, int>>[] metricGetters = 
{
    s => s.Impressions,
    s => s.Clicks,
    s => s.Spent,
};

// Cache this; don't create it each time.
var updater = GetAggregateUpdater(metricGetters);

var delta = new AdStatsItem
{
    Impressions = 100,
    Clicks = 4,
    Spent = 33,
};

var hourly = new AdStatsItem
{
    Impressions = 2000,
    Clicks = 140,
    Spent = 400,
};

updater(hourly, delta);
```

Comment: Actually, the solution with expression trees only is exactly what i was looking for. As far as i understand, the cost of calling the compiled delegate is pretty much the same as if i would have it statically implemented.

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same (if you ignore the call-overhead of a delegate - roughly comparable to a virtual method call). Benchmark to test.